# Issues with insert/creating a record in custom object using custom controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, controller-extension, custom-controller

VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Applications__c" lightningStylesheets="true">
<apex:sectionHeader title="Application For Employment"/>
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" showHeader="true" title="Application For Employment">
        <apex:inputField value="{!Applications__c.Full_Name__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Applications__c.Job_Posting__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Applications__c.Company__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Applications__c.Positions__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Applications__c.Phone__c}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockSection> 

      <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
        <apex:commandButton value="Insert" action="{!save}" />
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Controller:

```
public class Applications_c { 
public Job_Posting__c Job_Posting{get; set;}
public Applications__c createapplication{get; set;}  

public void createapplication() {
    createapplication = new Applications__c();
}
public PageReference saveApplication() {
    insert createapplication;
    return null;
}
```

}

This is my code to be able to insert a new application. It doesnt create a new record, not getting any errors.

Comment: FYI, Your page is using the SObject and save method of the standard controller (a built-in general purpose controller); you have not hooked in your custom controller class. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm for how to do that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

VF page :

```
<apex:page controller="Applications" lightningStylesheets="true">
<apex:sectionHeader title="Application For Employment"/>
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
  <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" showHeader="true" title="Application For Employment">
    <apex:inputField value="{!createapplication.Full_Name__c}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!createapplication.Job_Posting__c}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!createapplication.Company__c}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!createapplication.Positions__c}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!createapplication.Phone__c}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockSection> 

  <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
    <apex:commandButton value="Insert" action="{!saveApplication}" />
  </apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Controller :

```
public class Applications { 
public Job_Posting__c Job_Posting{get; set;}
public Applications__c createapplication{get; set;}  

public Applications() {
    createapplication = new Applications__c();
}
public PageReference saveApplication() {
    insert createapplication;
    return null;
}
```

Changes needed :

- you have to use controller in VF page for custom controller.
- created one constructor and initialized the createapplication object.
- used createapplication object in VF page in input field.
- on button action was save. but you have written saveApplication method to save so replaced action from "save" with "saveApplication".

Comment: Hi @patelkiran3090, I downvoted your answer because you just dumped a few code lines without any information. Please consider editing your answer and provide explanations about the suggested solution so OP can learn for next time.

Comment: i did not dumped. i changed his code only and changed some things which was wrong. which anyone can understand by comparing code. added description now. is this okay? or you need some more information?